# HTML 5 internet-explorer-8 html javascript

Tags: html

Does IE9 support any HTML5 elements?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: [html5 readiness](http://html5readiness.com/), some additional information on [Wired](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/09/internet-explorer-9-beta-drops-its-lean-fast-and-modern/) (albeit it's a preview/review, rather than a technical evaluation):

> IE9 supports much of HTML5, and there’s a new parser to handle the new markup language. There’s support for native playback of audio and video files, and the Canvas element, with support for animated 2-D polygons and text. HTML5 selection is supported, but not drag-and-drop or Microdata.
>
> The Scalable Vector Graphics, or SVG, standard is supported, and like other animation and media features in the browser, it can take advantage of hardware acceleration.
>
> There’s finally real support for CSS 3 in this release — media queries, borders and backgrounds, selectors, the fonts module and the Web Open Font Format, or WOFF, rich type standard, among other things.
>
> From: [Wired IE9 (p)review](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/09/internet-explorer-9-beta-drops-its-lean-fast-and-modern/).